# produce a matrix of strings on the basis of a list

Tags: python

I want to produce a matrix on the basis of this data I have:

[[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0], [0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]

What I want to do, is if the sum inside the square brackets is equal to 1, produce a string variable y_n where n is the counter of lists meeting that condition,
and yxn if the sum is greater than one, where n counts the number of strings produced.
So for my data it should produce:

```
y_1 
y_2
yx1
yx2
```

up to

```
yx7
```

So my best attempt is:

```
if len(gcounter) != 0:
  hg = len(gcounter[0])
else:
  hg=1
  LHS=Matrix(hg,1,lambda i,j:(var('yx%d' %i)))
print(LHS)
```

The data is called gcounter.

It's not giving me an error, but its not filling LHS up with anything

Comment: And where does this class `Matrix` come from?

Comment: That's from Sympy. I'll try your solution tomorrow @Blckknght many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're doing, but I think this generator does what you want:

```
def gen_y_strings(data):
    counter_1 = counter_other = 0
    for item in data:
        if sum(item) == 1:
            counter_1 += 1
            yield "y_{}".format(counter_1)
        else:
            counter_other += 1
            yield "yx{}".format(counter_other)
```

You can run it like this:

```
for result in gen_y_strings(gcounter):
    print(result)
```

Which, given the example data, outputs what you wanted:

```
y_1
y_2
yx1
yx2
yx3
yx4
yx5
yx6
yx7
```